# how to save and read map in mongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb, dictionary

i have a collection in mongo that contains 3 column as below:

```
{ 
"_id" : { "$oid" : "5396ad5de4b09ea27a641ed6"} , 
"word" : "test_word" , 
"doc_occurrence" : "'total':25,'sport':10" ,
 "total_occurrence" : "'total':32,'sport':15"
}
```

doc_occurrence and total_occurrence are Map. i insert documents to collection this way:

```
        private boolean add(String word, Map<String, Integer> docOccurrence, Map<String, Integer> totalOccurrence) {
    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("word", word);
    document.put("docOccurrence", docOccurrence);
    document.put("totalOccurrence", totalOccurrence);
    try {
        synchronized (LOCK_WRITE) {
            table.insert(WriteConcern.SAFE,document);


        }
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        logger.error("Could not insert new row to word_cat : {}", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

i want to read maps from DB this way:

```
        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("word",word);
    try {
        DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);
        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject doc = cursor.next();
            Map<String, Integer> map = (Map<String, Integer>)doc.get("docOccurrence"); // ClassCastException
```

but i get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

is there any way i cat read maps directly from DB? if not, what is altenative?

p.s: BSON convert map to String. in fact BSON keys must be String!

Comment: This cast is almost surely illegal! The best you can do (I am no mongo expert) is to find a Java Map compatible class in the Mongo connection Library.
If you can't find any just read the doc.get(...) as String and somehow convert it to a Map manually, creating a method only for this...

Comment: It looks like your saving of the map does not work properly and the map is stored as a flat `String`.

Comment: BSON convert map to String,but i dont know how i can manage this.

Comment: Which MongoDB driver are you using?

Comment: i use mongo-java-driver-2.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have created your BSON object with the `Map` part placed in the "string" size of the constructor, so there is an implicit "stringify" in there in this invocation.

Wrapped as the sole argument to a BSON Object constructor then then `Map` serializes properly:

```
document.put("word", word);
document.put("docOccurrence", new BasicDBObject(docOccurrence));
document.put("totalOccurrence", new BasicDBObject(totalOccurrence));
```

The BasicDBObject class implements the AbstractMap interface and should be able to be used that way on data that is read. The rest of the code should work as expected.

Comment: @zsh Works for me. But this won't fix data you have already saved to MongoDB. What I am pointing out is the problem you introduced when saving it. To fix any data that is just strings you will have to manually split it and re-cast as a Map and then save again by the correct code I have shown.

Comment: yes it works! i did't remove data already saved to mongoDB :D
thanks a lot :)

Comment: it's because that answer hint me a good idea, and i gusse i was wrong for coding this way. so what is the problem with rambling on the other "answer"? :)

Comment: @zsh It's not an answer, just an extended comment that has turned into a series of comments. There is nothing wrong with what you were coding apart from the correction that was given in the answer here. I notice that you both have sufficient privilege level to open a chat discussion separate to the question, which might be more appropriate is all I am saying.

Comment: okay,thanks for your remembering,i have another question : can i update map <key: value> directly in mobgoDB? or i have to get map completely and update that way?

Comment: @zsh If you have another question then please feel free to post another question which I am sure someone will answer. If there was anything in the discussion that occurred there, then there was the mention of "dot notation". You can either search for sources or post another question to clear up what you do not understand. It may even be considered useful and up-voted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read more about MongoDB and NoSQL  because you seem really confused about the whole concept.

You have a **collection** in mongodb that has a **document** that has 3 **fields** , excluding the _id . Your **doc_occurrence** and **total_occurrence** fields should have their values as **subdocument**s(another json object) , that's how MongoDB rolls . Your usage of string csv values instead of subdocuments is completely ineffective and wrong.

Comment: so if i want to having subdocument,i should use what structure? i need to read my collectionn data as an object like wordInfo that contains  String for word, map for docOccurence and map for totalOcurrence

Comment: subdocument is json object , just like every document in mongodb is

Comment: what javatype is suitable for keepping a subdocument?is map okay?

Comment: where do you want to keep it ? if you want to process it , you should use JSON http://www.json.org/java/

Comment: i need to access data as key value,but if i save data as map,data updating become difficult because i have to get map completely and update it,but for sub socument i can update value of subdocument field directly.

Comment: No. You can easily update values in subdocuments by dot notation. for example , you can reach the value like doc_occurrence.total and read or change it.

Comment: even if i save docOccurrence as map?

Comment: This really reads more like a rant. The problem was the incorrect passing of a raw Map into a BSON Object (BasicDBObject). When cast properly it works fine. The content of the answer didn't really offer anything to solve the problem. Just for future reference.

Comment: the OP is using MongoDB and has no idea about entities of the domain , which is the root of all his future questions.